# Difference between `http.request.clone()` and `new Request(request.clone())`

Tags: httprequest, clone

This is about [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) object.

I have seen both approaches, and was wondering if there is any real difference between the 2, is one a more correct or faster approach?

1. Cloning a htttp.request object using [request.clone()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/clone)
2. Cloning a htttp.request object using `new Request(request.clone())`